# Is there a Session variable in Spring Boot

Tags: php, spring-boot, session

Is there a Session variable in Spring Boot like the $_SESSION["IsLoggedIn"] in PHP? I need to use it so that I can make the 'Login' and 'Register' disappear from the header and make the 'Log Out' Button appear in the header. If not can sommeone direct me to a method or something similiar, since I couldn't find anything

Comment: Don't. Use Spring Security and its tag library instead. Don't try to write your own security implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't really understand your comment. Are you saying that there is a session tag in the Spring Security Library?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should be using Spring Security for protecting your application and that you shouldn't be writing your own security library. There is an `HttpSession` which is part of the regular Servlet API. But you really shouldn't try to write your own security framework. Use a proven one like Spring Security or Apache Shiro instead, those have handy utilities to use in web pages to conditionally render parts.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways you can do that:-

1. Using HttpSession
2. Principal object

HttpSession is the same as PHP session

To get the Principal object you have to use this line as an arg in your controller methods

```
@AuthenticationPrincipal UserPrincipal principal
```

Example:-

```
@RequestMapping("/success")
public String success(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserPrincipal principal,
                      HttpSession httpSession){

    httpSession.setAttribute("loggedUser", principal.getUsername());
    return "index";
}
```

This example will give you a rough idea about both

Also sharing with you my UserPrincipal Class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

private final Users user;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return user.getName();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}